# Swift Execute function once a day with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm making the app which calculate user's credit **once a day.**

I'm using Swift3, Firebase(with completion), TableView.

My Swift Algorithm is here...

```
viewDidLoad() {
  getDaysDB {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}

getDaysDB() {
   **get some value from Firebase**
   creditLevel() 
   completion()
}

creditLevel() {
   **calculate credit**
}
```

But the problem is Every time I check credit, Function is executed. So Credit is endlessly increased... And I just want to execute function only one time a day.

So I thought that i need kind of a timestamp, but have no idea How Can I use timestamp with my code.

Any nice and cool tip from you..? Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea: you can use Timer/DateTime check & UserDefaults. For example you can set some setting in UserDefaults "Performed Calculation" which will contain date of last call of the function. Every run your app should check if setting contains today's date or not. If yes - skip, if not - call calc. + you can use Timer to run it every XXX seconds.

Comment: You can use local notification.

Comment: @DJ-Glock Thanks for your idea. I will try with this, So thankful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea: you can use Timer/DateTime check & UserDefaults. For example you can set some setting in UserDefaults "Performed Calculation" which will contain date of last call of the function. Every run your app should check if setting contains today's date or not. If yes - skip, if not - call calc. + you can use Timer to run it every XXX seconds.